# Git workflow for multiple projects based on my own seed project?

Tags: git, github, workflow, git-remote, boilerplate

I'm creating a seed project (for myself) which I will use as a base for multiple other projects. After searching for best practices for doing this I have found a few useful strategies. But I'm not convinced which strategy to use and I don't feel like I have a complete solution; a workflow that explains all steps necessary to satisfy my needs.

So far I have found 2 main strategies.

1. Use multiple remotes:

`git clone -o seed ssh://git@github.com/user/seed.git new_project_name`
The -o seed renames the origin to `seed` which can still be used to pull changes from.

Create your new empty GitHub new_project_name repo.
Then
`git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/user/new_project_name.git`

([What is the proper git workflow for basing a project off a 'seed' repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380705/what-is-the-proper-git-workflow-for-basing-a-project-off-a-seed-repo))

2. Use multiple branches:

`git clone https://github.com/username/seed.git`/n

`git branch myproject`

`git checkout myproject`

All of your changes will be independent from the seed project. If you want to keep up to date and see where the seed project is all you need to do is this:

`git checkout master`

`git pull`

Now all of your files will be gone and you will see what the latest stuff in 'seed' looks like. If you wish for your project to get their changes you would do this:

`git checkout myproject`

`git merge master`

([How to organise git repos when building on a seed project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169259/how-to-organise-git-repos-when-building-on-a-seed-project))

If I use the 'multiple remotes' strategy I assume I will not be able to push any changes I make to the code which originate from the seed project since the seed project will then get all code related to the project I'm pushing from (?).

If I use the 'multiple branch' strategy I assume I will have to push all projects to my seed repo as different branches (?). If I want to change any code which originate from the seed project I can always checkout and change the master and then merge changes to the branch(es).

I feel like I'm suppose to use some kind of mix between these two strategies (or something completely different). Because straight away I ran into the problem that I wanted to change the readme.md, package.json, gulpfile, etc. in each project (which is based on the seed project). If I then `git pull` any improvements made to the seed project I assume the changes to these files will get overwritten, or at least there is a big risk of having to deal with constant merge issues. What strategy should I use to make these potentially messy issues as simple as possible to deal with?

(I was also looking into forking but it doesn't seem relevant unless all repositories are just alternative versions of the same software (?) and you want one person to be in charge of merging to the main version (?). )